# serenity properties does not work for safari

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safaridriver, cucumber-serenity

In my setup, I am running my tests for CucumberWithSerenity.class
The issue is after execution of my tests with safari browser, safari does not clear the cookies and other related data. e.g. After login steps are completed, i have to search for a user and set the user so i get relevant sections. But safari retains the set user information from previous test execution. To address this issue, i have set the following in serenity.properties file : safari.options.useCleanSession=true
however, this does not seem to work.

On other browsers, i do not have such an issue. Am i implementing the property incorrectly?

Are there other options in ensuring that every time safari browser is launched, i have fresh new session?

Can you please provide an example?

Comment: What version of safaridriver and Safari are you using?

Comment: Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8)